# Running python script in Visual Studio Code; how to get `input ()` to work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to grab a simple **input** using `input()`, but when I run the script within *Visual Code* the program hangs whenever that line of code is hit.

- How can I run code within *Visual Studio Code* and use `input()`?

---

<sub>**task**</sub>

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    "command": "python",

    "isShellCommand": true,

    "showOutput": "always",

    "args": ["${file}"],
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Introduction

You will need to run your script from the *command-line* (terminal), instead of directly in *Visual Studio Code*, if you would like to interact with the program as a normal user would.

```
> python name_of_program.py
```

---

#### Elaboration

The output displayed inside *Visual Studio Code* is not meant to be used for interacting with the underlying script, nor does it have the capability to read any input directly from your keyboard (it simply shows the output of whatever you have decided to run).

---

#### Workaround

What you could do is to edit your task-file to automatically spawn a terminal of your choosing instead of running the `python`-interpreter directly.

Depending on what operating system you are on, and the terminals available, the edits required to do this might look a little different, but they should all follow the same pattern.

```
{
           "version": "0.1.0",
           "command": "urxvt",
    "isShellCommand": false,
        "showOutput": "always",
              "args": [ "-e", "python ${file}" ]  
}
```

> <sub>**N O T E**
> In the above, *`urxvt`* is the name of my choice for terminal, *`-e`* is the flag required to pass a command that is to be executed upon startup, and `python ${file}` is the command to execute.
>
> My recommendation is to get the command necessary to fire up a new terminal, and directly execute a python script, working elsewhere before editing your *task*-file.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much ! @Filip
Although if it would have been better to run right in VS Code, I think this the best workaround !

Comment: Do not forget to upvote the answer, and [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/285262), to flag this question as "solved"! Welcome to stackoverflow, @AndreaTulimiero!

Comment: I'd like to but I don't have enough repo ! @Filip

Comment: However I marked it as the best answer
Thx again Man ! @Filip

Comment: @AndreaTulimiero now you do! ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can right click within the text file that you wish to run and then select "Run Python file in Terminal".

Comment: This appears to be the most straight forward and correct answer.

Comment: Do you know how to create keyboard shortcut for this option?

Comment: @Tobol `[
    { "key": "cmd+r", "command": "python.execInTerminal" }
]`

Comment: Another good one is ``[ { "key": "cmd+r", "command": "python.execSelectionInTerminal" } ]``

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I guess you ran the program with

ctrl + shift + B for build.

instead of build, you can simply open up terminal inside of vs code by

ctrl + shift + `

once terminal is opened, type in the name of file you'd like to run.

Answer (score 0):

just click on the RUN CODE
option at the top right corner of visual studio ode interference. When you run code it automatically runs (input()) function in Terminal.