# Running Python code inside Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I've recently set up Python inside Visual Studio Code, and I use an extention called [Code Runner](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner) to execute the python. The onlyproblem is, it doesn't allow input into the terminal, so if I run code that includes the `input` function, the whole IDE freezes, no way to get out of it or re-run the code as it says its already running, and I have to restart the IDE.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to File > Preferences -> User Settings and add this:

```
    {
        "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
    }
```

For more information, refer to:

https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/91

Also, you can always just use the python IDE if nothing works, if it isn't a problem. There is another thread with python input and Visual studio here: [Running python script in Visual Studio Code; how to get `input ()` to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944233/running-python-script-in-visual-studio-code-how-to-get-input-to-work)

Comment: I know this is OCD, but the original terminal has 4 lines which also get printed on each debug, which annoy me. But thanks, this is the closest I've got.